# Using the adjective "expressive" to mean an object allows for expression?

Tags: meaning, adjectives, word-usage

My intention is to say that systems of a particular type allow users to express ideas on them. I wanted to give the concept a more concise/general name, as a title for such systems.

I called them *Expressive Systems* initially, but I realise that this may not be correct (it may, I don't know) because this seems to mean more that the system is able to express certain things on its own. This isn't even close to what I intended.

Does the adjective "expressive" in this context mean what I intend to mean? If not, what form of the word (or other replacement word) should I use to express my intention?

Comment: This reminds me of Objective-C..

Comment: hmm... You just brought me to one more question: Does Expressive-System mean the same as Expressive System?

Comment: It would be easier to answer this question if you explained the system in question. Particularly address this point: Is the system itself a method of expression, or are these "expressions" integral to the function of the system, or are the expressions intended to be comments upon the system itself, or is this system some type of communication conduit?

Comment: Find an abstract word to name your system so users don't get as confused as ... is/are right now. You could with words like -*xprezzion* (which makes no sense). That would let the users find the sense for themselves. Your catch phrase could then do the trick. Something like, *express yourself!* Sorry though, I'm suppose to be teaching better English here, but that should be for English not names of Systems.

Comment: @JohnM.Landsberg Thanks for bringing this up. Yes, the system I'm referring to is a method of expression. Perhaps like writing, films, etc. I'm trying to convey the idea that these are "systems" that allows for expressions. But again, calling them expressive systems would seem to change the actual meanings.

Answer (score 0):

Users expressive systems? That way it's a clearer meaning of being for the people, rather than the system itself.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I think the right word would be *impressionable* — if that word did not have its negative connotation.